# Add n-textfields with same fieldName with iText

Tags: java, itext, textfield

i want to use iText to add textfields sharing the same fieldName to a document. The purpose is to be able to set one value and the value should appear on all pages (auto-fill).

My problem is, that with the following code only the first TextField appears in Adobe Reader. After researching it looks like i have to use "one dictionary entry" and multiple visual representations "widgets", but i have no clue how to implement that with iText.

Any suggestions?
thanks
Siegfried

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TextField;

public class ITextAddTextfieldDemo {
    private static final String ORIGINAL = "original.pdf";
    private static final String RESULT = "original_textfield.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            DocumentException {
        ITextAddTextfieldDemo.createPdf(ORIGINAL, 5);
        ITextAddTextfieldDemo.stamp(ORIGINAL, RESULT);

        System.out.println("done");
    }

    public static void stamp(String src, String dest) throws IOException,
            DocumentException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new File(src).getAbsolutePath());
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));

        int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();

        // test problem by switching true/false
        boolean uniqueName = false;
        String fieldName = "demoField";

        if (uniqueName) {
            TextField textField = new TextField(stamper.getWriter(),
                    new Rectangle(560, 600, 590, 800), fieldName);
            textField.setText(""); // add text to see misrendered output
            textField.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE | TextField.DO_NOT_SCROLL);
            textField.setRotation(90);

            for (int page = 1; page <= pages; page++) {
                stamper.addAnnotation(textField.getTextField(), page);
            }
        } else {
            TextField[] textFields = new TextField[pages];
            for (int page = 1; page <= pages; page++) {
                int idx = page - 1;
                fieldName += "_" + String.valueOf(page);

                textFields[idx] = new TextField(stamper.getWriter(),
                        new Rectangle(560, 600, 590, 800), fieldName);
                textFields[idx].setText(""); // add text to see misrendered output
                textFields[idx].setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE
                        | TextField.DO_NOT_SCROLL);
                textFields[idx].setRotation(90);

                stamper.addAnnotation(textFields[idx].getTextField(), page);
            }
        }

        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }

    public static void createPdf(String filename, int pages)
            throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        document.open();

        for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello page " + String.valueOf(i + 1));
            document.add(p);
            document.newPage();
        }

        document.close();
    }

}
```

@EDIT: I found a solution but i still have a question. Is this the suggested way and why do i have to stamp the parent on each page? (Stamping it only on the first page doesn't work).

```
if (uniqueName) {
    PdfFormField parent = PdfFormField.createTextField(
            stamper.getWriter(), true, false, 0);
    parent.setFieldName(fieldName);
    parent.setUserName("Please enter the common demo data.");

    for (int page = 1; page <= pages; page++) {
        TextField textField = new TextField(stamper.getWriter(),
                new Rectangle(560, 600, 590, 800), null);
        textField.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE
                | TextField.DO_NOT_SCROLL);
        textField.setRotation(90);
        PdfFormField pff = textField.getTextField();
        parent.addKid(pff);

        stamper.addAnnotation(pff, page);
        // why is it necessary to add it on every page?
        stamper.addAnnotation(parent, page);
    }

} else {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add the parent to each page.  You can set the page for each widget using PdfAnnotation.setPlaceInPage(pagenumber) and add the parent once.  I have adjusted the solution you added to your question:

```
    if (uniqueName) {
        PdfFormField parent = PdfFormField.createTextField(
                stamper.getWriter(), true, false, 0);
        parent.setFieldName(fieldName);
        parent.setUserName("Please enter the common demo data.");

        for (int page = 1; page <= pages; page++) {
            TextField textField = new TextField(stamper.getWriter(),
                    new Rectangle(560, 600, 590, 800), null);
            textField.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE
                    | TextField.DO_NOT_SCROLL);
            textField.setRotation(90);
            PdfFormField pff = textField.getTextField();
            parent.addKid(pff);
            // add widget to each page
            pff.setPlaceInPage(page);
        }
        // add parent
        stamper.addAnnotation(parent, 1);
    } else {
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the adding of the fonts /Helv and /ZaDb in PdfStamperImp.addFieldResources()?

Comment: In this way we can add only one Textfield to each page but how can we add multiple textfields in different coordinate in  a single or multiple pages.