# Remove page reference from annotation

Tags: java, itext, autofill, form-fields, formfield

I added a textfield with several kids similar as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212745/add-n-textfields-with-same-fieldname-with-itext). Did that to use the autofill functionality of PDF...
Now my question is how am I able to remove the page reference from the parent element? The data field should not contain a parent reference since it is not related to any page. The widgets should contain those (which I added there however I can't remove the parent /P page reference)

I tried

```
PdfFormField parent = PdfFormField.createTextField(stamper.getWriter(), false, false, 0);
parent.setFieldName(fieldName);

for (int page = 1; page <= pages; page++) {
    TextField textField = new TextField(stamper.getWriter(), new Rectangle(560, 600, 590, 800), null);

    PdfFormField pff = textField.getTextField();
    parent.addKid(pff);
    // add widget to each page
    pff.setPlaceInPage(page);
    //iText workarounds
    field.put(PdfName.P, stamper.getWriter().getPageReference(page));
    field.remove(PdfName.FF);
    field.remove(PdfName.FT);
}
//in addAnnotation() the page reference is written
stamper.addAnnotation(parent, 1);
//does not work
parent.remove(PdfName.P);
```

however it didn't work since I guess the page reference is already written. Is there a way to remove it afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fact 1:**

The `PdfFormField` class extends the `PdfAnnotation` class, because most of the times, it is possible to merge a field dictionary with an annotation dictionary.

In your case, you have a `PdfFormField` that is used as a hierarchical element and although that element is also an instance of `PdfAnnotation`, it isn't. You can check this by using the `isAnnotation()` method. It will return `false`.

**Fact 2:**

When you add an annotation to an existing PDF, you have to use `PdfStamper`'s `addAnnotation()` method that not only accepts an annotation object, but also a page number. If you didn't add a page number, `PdfStamper` wouldn't know where to add the annotation.

When you add a real annotation, `PdfStamper` will add a `/P` key that refers to the page where the annotations is visualized.

**Fact 3:**

There is no other way than using `addAnnotation()` with an annotation and a page number when working with `PdfStamper`. When you add a `PdfFormField` object that is not a real annotation, it won't be treated differently, hence a `/P` entry will be added, although that doesn't really make sense (as you rightly point out in your question).

**Fact 4:**

The `/P` entry is optional. For the widget annotations to be displayed correctly, it is sufficient that they appear in the `/Annots` of a page.

**Conclusion:**

iText shouldn't add a `/P` entry in case you add a `PdfFormField` that is not a real annotation. Hence I have committed the following change: [revision 6756](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/6756/)

```
     void addAnnotation(PdfAnnotation annot, int page) {
-     annot.setPage(page);
+        if (annot.isAnnotation())
+            annot.setPage(page);
         addAnnotation(annot, reader.getPageN(page));
     }
```

I have tested this with the [AddFieldAndKids](https://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/AddFieldAndKids) example and it seems to work: the `/P` entry is no longer added.

This solves your problem in a more robust way. You shouldn't try to remove something that shouldn't have been added in the first place.